# Installation of teXlive on Windows fails

Tags: texlive, installing, windows

I tried to install teXlive on my laptop running Windows 8.1.
After unpacking, I ran "install-tl-windows.bat". It seemed OK for most of the installation, but then I got this in the terminal (the log file is the same):

```
Installing [2321/3058, time/total: 01:06:55/01:24:53]: qsymbols [136k]
Installing [2322/3058, time/total: 01:06:57/01:24:55]: qtree [213k]
xzdec: (stdin): Unexpected end of input
tar: Only read 5840 bytes from archive C:\texlive\2015\temp\qtree.doc.tar
untar: untarring C:\texlive\2015\temp\qtree.doc.tar failed (in C:\texlive\2015\texmf-dist)
untarring C:\texlive\2015\temp\qtree.doc.tar failed, stopping install.
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
Or you can restart by running the installer with:
  install-tl.bat --profile installation.profile [EXTRA-ARGS]
```

Notice that it failed close to the end, at package 2322/3058. My texlive folder is already 4.4GB. I tried reinstalling, it redownloaded everything, and failed again near the end. If there is any way to continue the installation from where it stopped, it would be great.

Comment: Have you tried a different mirror. It seems a downloaded file is damaged.

Answer (score 11):

I've been facing the same problem since TeX Live 2015 was released last month (I have Windows 7 Pro 64-bit OS). I've tried installing it every week (in the hopes that there is a bug, which will be fixed in the weekly updates) but no luck. I tried installing it from different mirrors but again no luck. Finally, I was able to figure out a workaround yesterday. Here's what I did:

1. Run install-tl-advanced.bat.
2. In the TeX Live 2015 windows that opens up, under Basic Information...Selected Scheme, click on Change
3. Select basic scheme (plain and latex) and click on Ok.
4. Now Selected Scheme should show scheme-basic.
5. Under Further Customization...Installation collections, it should
   now show 3 collections out of 48.
6. Click on Install TeX Live.
7. This installs a basic version of Tex Live (around 88 files).
8. Once this is installed, open the Tex Live 2015 Manager and then install all the packages you want.

This worked perfectly for me and TeX Live 2015 is up and running on my computer.
Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The solution for me was embarrassingly simple, I posted it now.

Comment: @MrX: I think you had a more specific issue rather than the general difficulty installing on Windows XP.

Comment: This worked for me where the net installer failed, but I first had to figure out that I had to run the conventional installer first, and select "unpack" in order to access install-tl-advanced.bat

Answer (score 2):

The problem turned out to be very simple - the error is generated when the computer gets locked after being idle for some time during the long installation.
Staying on the computer solved it.

Comment: That's not what I experienced.

Comment: Same problem here. This solution doesn't work for me though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. However, during the installation, you can read a warning to switch off your virus scanner. This indeed helped, and I guess that the virus scanner was also the reason why I had nearly the same problem with Miktex (which I therefore uninstalled).

Comment: Sorry, I did not want to imply that they are the same. I only wanted to suggest that 1.) I solved the problem described in this thread by switching off the virus scanner, which may work for other people as well, and that 2.) if somebody should stumble across this thread while having similar problems with Miktex (which I had on the same day some hours earlier) it may be a good idea to try switching off the virus scanner as well, as I find it likely that it would have helped in my case as well (and the cost of trying is close to zero).