# TeXLive installation failed: Inappropriate I/O control operation at TLPDB.pm line 359

Tags: texlive, installing, windows

I am trying to install texlive on my Windows 7 32 bit PC. Here is what I've done:

- Downloaded and extracted install-tl.zip.
- Added path to Perl and Wget to my environment variable PATH.
- since I am behind a proxy server, I command

  `set http_proxy=http://username:password@123.45.67.89:9090
  set https_proxy=https://username:password@123.45.67.89:9090`
- `cd` to \install-tl-20161124
- `install-tl-advanced.bat -gui=perltk`

It gives the following "Inappropriate I/O control operation" error, and quits installation:
`C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\install-tl-20161124\install-tl: open tlpdb(http://ctan.imsc.
res.in/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb) failed: Inappropriate I/O control operation at C:/Us
ers/AQ/Desktop/install-tl-20161124/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm line 359.`

The post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250820/installation-of-texlive-on-windows-fails) suggests to try a different mirror. I have tried different mirrors by using `--repository` option for the `install-tl-advanced.bat` command. But the result is same.

A similar issue has also been reported on the texlive mailing list [here](https://lists.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2016-September/039301.html) a couple of months back. But I could not find any solution there.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I get a very similar error message on OSX when trying to run tlmgr update --self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently it should, but it does not work when given the option `-gui=____` along with the `install-tl-advanced.bat`. It is working fine without giving the `-gui` option.