# Installation of teXlive on Windows fails

Tags: texlive, installing

I tried to install TeXlive on my laptop running Windows 10.

```
Installing [3110/3342, time/total: 01:23:03/01:29:44]: udesoftec [618k] 
Installing [3111/3342, time/total: 01:23:05/01:29:45]: uebungsblatt [226k]
Installing [3112/3342, time/total: 01:23:06/01:29:45]: uestcthesis [4168k]
Installing [3113/3342, time/total: 01:23:10/01:29:39]: uhc [3517k]
untar: untarring C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\mTonFCCsKX\3U9pWgDmDk\uhc.tar failed (in C:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist)

TLPDB::_install_package: untar failed
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
Or you can restart by running the installer with:
  install-tl-windows.bat --profile installation.profile [EXTRA-ARGS]
or
  install-tl-advanced.bat --profile installation.profile [EXTRA-ARGS]
```

Please give a hand and a solution on it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked questions with similar tags and problems? For example http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254252/79756

Comment: Thank you for your reminding! I have install a plain version.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with similar problems and got it working now.
What I have done differently now:

- Store installer on same hard drive partition as the installation.
- Run `install-tl-advanced.bat` instead of `install-tl-windows.bat`.

Hope this helps anybody else.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check your environment variables for other tar.exe files, I had one from mingw that caused the problem. Removing the mingw bin folder (temporary) from the path solved the problem.

Comment: Well, can you add an screenshot of what you mean? What is `mingw` that it couses such an issue? Please explain better why that is a solution (we do not know the OP uses `mingw` too ...) BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Good hint for me. Seems like the installer is takeing the first tar executable it can find (in my case the one from mingw which was available based on the PATH variable of my system environment) without making sure it is a compatible one.

Answer (score -1):

Deactivating microsoft's real time protection solved the problem for me.

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx.