# Installing Tex live problem installing packages

Tags: texstudio, windows, texlive-2017

I install Tex-studio. Then I install basic-miktex-2.9.5872-x64 but it does not support some package and does not install dictionary. Therefore I install Tex-Live from internet [Tex-live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). For Installing i followed the instruction of  [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250820/installation-of-texlive-on-windows-fails). But still have problem texstudio does not install packages. It give error message while compiling it. Also the dictionary not install in it.

> File `ragged2e.sty' not found.
>   File`lmodern.sty' not found. \usepackage

I am depressed with these kind of error messages but i cannot remove it. Please help me to resolve my issue. How can i Install all packages.

my latex code is:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,oneside,final]{article}


\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{PrintVersion}
\setboolean{PrintVersion}{false}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb Q}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb F}
\newcommand{\G}{\mathbb G}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\parindent = 0pt
%\usepackage{nomencl} % For a nomenclature (optional; available from ctan.org)
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext,amsfonts} % Lots of math symbols and environments
%\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
%\newtheorem{de}{Defination}
%\newtheorem{ex}{Example}
%\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
%\newtheorem{pro}{Proposition}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%
{3pt}%
{3pt}%
{\normalfont}%
{}%
{\bfseries}%
{\newline}%
{1em}%
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}%
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{de}{Defination}[section]

\newtheoremstyle{inline}%
{3pt}%
{3pt}%
{\normalfont}%
{}%
{\bfseries}%
{}%
{1em}%
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}%
\theoremstyle{inline}
\newtheorem{ex}[de]{Example}
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%
{3pt}%
{3pt}%
{\normalfont}%
{}%
{\bfseries}%
{\newline}%
{1em}%
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}%
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} % For including graphics N.B. pdftex graphics driver
%\usepackage[]{natbib}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}

\linespread{1.05}         % Palatino needs more leading (space between lines)
% Hyperlinks make it very easy to navigate an electronic document.
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[pdftex,letterpaper=true,pagebackref=false]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{array}
\usepackage{floatrow}


\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm,algorithmicx}
\newcommand*\DNA{\textsc{dna}}

\newcommand*\Let[2]{\State #1 $\gets$ #2}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Precondition:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Postcondition:}}
\usepackage{cryptocode}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}




 \smallskipamount.
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1} % this is the default line space setting

\let\origdoublepage\cleardoublepage
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
  \clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\origdoublepage}}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearemptydoublepage

\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% FRONT MATERIAL
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\makethesisfrontpages
\input{frontpages/frontpages}


% Change page numbering back to Arabic numerals
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\rhead{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% MAIN BODY

\input{chapter1/introduction}

\input{chapter2/chap2}

\input{chapter3/chap3}

\input{chapter4/chap4}


\input{appendices/appendices}   % UN-COMMENT IF YOU NEED TO ADD APPENDICES

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% END MATERIAL
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

% B I B L I O G R A P H Y
% -----------------------

% The following statement selects the style to use for references.  It controls the sort order of the entries in the bibliography and also the formatting for the in-text labels.

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
% This specifies the location of the file containing the bibliographic information.
\cleardoublepage % This is needed if the book class is used, to place the anchor in the correct page,
                 % because the bibliography will start on its own page.
                 % Use \clearpage instead if the document class uses the "oneside" argument

\phantomsection  % With hyperref package, enables hyperlinking from the table of contents to bibliography
% The following statement causes the title "References" to be used for the bibliography section:
\renewcommand*{\bibname}{References}

% Add the References to the Table of Contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{References}}

\bibliography{my_bib}
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Texstudio is neither part of MiKTeX nor of TeX Live. See [Dictionary for TeXstudio: “No dictionary Available”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87650/dictionary-for-texstudio-no-dictionary-available) about installation of dictionaries.

Comment: You need to update your packages , solution for unix machine  open terminal as root then type `tlmgr update --all`@sam

Comment: `ragged2e.sty` and `lmodern.sty` are available as MiKTeX package and also as part of TeX Live. With MiKTeX use either the MiKTeX package manager to install them, or configure MiKTeX to install packages on the fly. With TeX Live they are part of the default (full) installation. If you've done a smaller installation use `tlmgr` to install them.

Comment: I install basic TeX Live. Is any way to install it complete?

Comment: @BikiTeron: No update available in cmd

Comment: Which version of texlive you are using@sam

Comment: 2017 @BikiTeron

Comment: Its better to post your mwe@sam

Comment: MWE(minimum working example) \documentclass{} to \end{document}@sam

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63322/discussion-between-sam-and-biki-teron).

Comment: try `texdoc ragged2e` in your terminal, what it gives output@sam

Comment: `texdoc` is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.