# TexLive installation; Windows Defender

Tags: texlive, installing, windows

After installing TeXStudio, I needed to install a latex distribution (chose TexLive) and thus downloaded the [install-tl-windows.exe](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) file.

A warning message prompted by the Microsoft Defender when starting the installer file,

[image: texlive installation file warning on windows]

*In all different softwares/installer files downloaded and installed on my Windows 10, I do not receive this warning.*

One of the comments from a discussion [Installation of teXlive on Windows fails](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250820/installation-of-texlive-on-windows-fails)

[image]

1. What could be the possible reason for this? and
2. Is it safe for my PC to proceed with the installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Unrecognized means just that. It does not mean it is bad. It means you need to make a decision.

You do not need to switch your antivirus off. Just click on the "more info" and it will ask you if you want to "run anyway".

2. Probably but only you will know where you downloaded the executable file

Some code is very well recognised, or is signed with a certificate that is recognized by Microsoft. There are different types of code signing certificates - some more expensive. The cheaper ones may take some time for a new software build to be recognised as widely enough used to be considered safe.

Comment: Right, I will make the decision. I feel dumb now for making a fuss over something quite simple as my first question here.

Thank you @Aubrey for taking time out!